# How do you unlock the newest island? (Cave, mountain, forest, etc.)

Tags: happy-street

I'm unsure how to unlock the newest island. There's a forest (1st to be unlocked), mountain (2nd), cave (3rd), and then on this newest "summer theme" update on the map it shows a new undiscovered place to unlock. I'm unsure how to unlock it, and when I can get it.

The reason I'm wondering is because I've saved up and bought some flooze for buying all the summer-themed stuff; I have basically all of them and sand floor, sand stone, beach floor, palm trees, everything. It looks really cool, like a beach! But now what I'm wondering is when you unlock the new place, will it come with a gate like the forest and mountain? Or not, like the cave? If so, how much room will it take up? I need to know!

I'm playing on iOS if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

It unlocks at level 25 after a series of quests.